# Mostrar el último registro de cada tipo de garantía

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo estas dos tablas:  una de garantia y  otra de objeto de garantia. Puede haber varias garantías de un objeto de garantía ya que se va renovar muchas veces.

```
CREATE TABLE TB_GARANTIA(
    ID_GARANTIA uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
    NUMERO_GARANTIA varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    MONTO_GARANTIA numeric(18, 2) NOT NULL,
    ID_CONTRATO varchar(50) NULL,
    ID_TIPO_GARANTIA varchar(100) NULL,
    ID_ASEGURADORA varchar(50) NULL,
    TIPO_INGRESO varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    ID_OBJETO_GARANTIA varchar(50) NULL,
    ESTADO_GARANTIA varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    CUSTODIO varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    FECHA_INGRESO date NOT NULL,
    DESCRIPCION_INGRESO varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
    FECHA_SISTEMA datetime NOT NULL,
    ID_USUARIO varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    ID_SESSION varchar(50) NULL,
    ID_HISTORICO int NOT NULL,
    ID_ESTADO varchar(5) NOT NULL,
    ID_CONTRATO_MODIFICACION varchar(100) NULL
), 
CREATE TABLE TB_OBJETO_GARANTIA(
    ID_OBJETO_GARANTIA uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
    NOMBRE_OBJETO_GARANTIA varchar(100) NULL
) ;
```

He formulado esta consulta que no me ha resultado ya que no trae todas las garantías,  siendo la ultima de cada tipo de Objeto_garantia en registro por la renovación que se realiza.

```
;with
    T_GARANTIA_ULTIMAS AS
    (       
        SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY ID_OBJETO_GARANTIA ORDER BY FECHA_SISTEMA DESC ) AS ROW_NUM 
        FROM TB_GARANTIA TG 
        WHERE  TG.ID_ESTADO='ACT' 
    ),
    T_GARANTIA AS
    (
        SELECT * FROM T_GARANTIA_ULTIMAS TG WHERE TG.ROW_NUM=1       
    )
    select * from T_GARANTIA
```

Answer (score 1):

Con una subconsulta lo solucionas. La subconsulta devuelve todas las últimas garantías, con el id y la fecha, máxima y con ello hacemos un `join` con la tabla de cabecera.

```
   SELECT *
   FROM TB_OBJETO_GARANTIA TOG 
   INNER JOIN (
      SELECT ID_GARANTIA, MAX(FECHA_INGRESO) AS fecha_max
      FROM TB_GARANTIA
      WHERE  TG.ID_ESTADO='ACT' 
      GROUP BY ID_GARANTIA
   ) TG ON TOG.ID_OBJETO_GARANTIA = TG.ID_GARANTIA
```

Answer (score 1):

Modifico la respuesta, ya que indicas que quieres un resultado. Te planteo dos opciones diferentes. Lo primero relleno las dos tablas con unas filas:

```
INSERT INTO TB_OBJETO_GARANTIA (ID_OBJETO_GARANTIA, NOMBRE_OBJETO_GARANTIA)
VALUES
('54FA719F-2673-47CC-94F0-1D64B70C31C0','OBJETO 1'),
('6087F59F-6037-4773-A9B8-3F87A25AED71','OBJETO 2'),
('A037F59F-6037-4773-A9B8-3F87A25AED71','OBJETO 3');
GO
```

Segunda Tabla

```
INSERT INTO TB_GARANTIA (ID_GARANTIA, NUMERO_GARANTIA, MONTO_GARANTIA,        ID_CONTRATO, ID_TIPO_GARANTIA, ID_ASEGURADORA,
TIPO_INGRESO, ID_OBJETO_GARANTIA, ESTADO_GARANTIA, CUSTODIO, FECHA_INGRESO,   DESCRIPCION_INGRESO, FECHA_SISTEMA,
ID_USUARIO, ID_SESSION, ID_HISTORICO, ID_ESTADO, ID_CONTRATO_MODIFICACION)
VALUES
(NEWID(), '1',    100.1,'IDCONTRATO','IDTIPOGARANTIA','IDASEGURADORA','IDTIPOINGRESO','54FA719F- 2673-47CC-94F0-1D64B70C31C0',
'ESTADOGAR','CUSTODIO','20190601','DESINGRESO','20200101','IDUSER','SESION',1,'ACT  ','IDCONTRATO'),
(NEWID(), '1',   200.1,'IDCONTRATO','IDTIPOGARANTIA','IDASEGURADORA','IDTIPOINGRESO','54FA719F- 2673-47CC-94F0-1D64B70C31C0',
'ESTADOGAR','CUSTODIO','20190101','DESINGRESO','20200101','IDUSER','SESION',2,'ACT  ','IDCONTRATO'),
(NEWID(), '1',  300.1,'IDCONTRATO','IDTIPOGARANTIA','IDASEGURADORA','IDTIPOINGRESO','54FA719F- 2673-47CC-94F0-1D64B70C31C0',
'ESTADOGAR','CUSTODIO','20181101','DESINGRESO','20200101','IDUSER','SESION',3,'ACT   ','IDCONTRATO'),
(NEWID(), '1',  500.1,'IDCONTRATO','IDTIPOGARANTIA','IDASEGURADORA','IDTIPOINGRESO','6087F59F-6037-4773-A9B8-3F87A25AED71',
'ESTADOGAR','CUSTODIO','20181101','DESINGRESO','20200101','IDUSER','SESION',3,'ACT','IDCONTRATO');
GO
```

Ahora disponemos de 3 objetos y de 4 lineas de garantía. 3 apuntan al primer objeto y una al segundo. El tercero no tiene garantía.

Primera opción utilzando ROW_NUMBER
    ;WITH OBJETOS AS 
    (
        SELECT * FROM TB_OBJETO_GARANTIA
    ),
    GARANTIAS AS 
    (

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID_OBJETO_GARANTIA ORDER BY FECHA_INGRESO DESC) AS ROW
  , TB_GARANTIA.ID_GARANTIA
 , TB_GARANTIA.NUMERO_GARANTIA
 , TB_GARANTIA.MONTO_GARANTIA
 , TB_GARANTIA.ID_CONTRATO
 , TB_GARANTIA.ID_TIPO_GARANTIA
 , TB_GARANTIA.ID_ASEGURADORA
 , TB_GARANTIA.TIPO_INGRESO
 , TB_GARANTIA.ID_OBJETO_GARANTIA
 , TB_GARANTIA.ESTADO_GARANTIA
 , TB_GARANTIA.CUSTODIO
 , TB_GARANTIA.FECHA_INGRESO
 , TB_GARANTIA.DESCRIPCION_INGRESO
 , TB_GARANTIA.FECHA_SISTEMA
 , TB_GARANTIA.ID_USUARIO
 , TB_GARANTIA.ID_SESSION
 , TB_GARANTIA.ID_HISTORICO
 , TB_GARANTIA.ID_ESTADO
 , TB_GARANTIA.ID_CONTRATO_MODIFICACION
   FROM TB_GARANTIA
)
    SELECT * FROM OBJETOS 
    LEFT JOIN GARANTIAS ON CAST(OBJETOS.ID_OBJETO_GARANTIA  AS VARCHAR(50))= 
GARANTIAS.ID_OBJETO_GARANTIA
WHERE GARANTIAS.ROW = 1 OR GARANTIAS.ROW IS NULL
```

Así obtienes tantas filas de objeto como garantías tenga. Si no tiene ninguna entonces las columnas relativas a la tabla Tb_Garantía se mostrarán como null.
Fíjate que utilizamos row_number order by fecha_ingreso desc, y luego obtenemos solo la primera fila, o si no tiene que sea null. 
Esto es para que nos devuelva también el objeto 3. Si no se da esta causística, entonces, puedes cambiar el left join por un inner join y quitar el or garantias.row is null

Segunda opción, utilizando el operador apply.

```
SELECT * FROM TB_OBJETO_GARANTIA O
OUTER APPLY
(
SELECT TOP(1)
      TB_GARANTIA.ID_GARANTIA
    , TB_GARANTIA.NUMERO_GARANTIA
    , TB_GARANTIA.MONTO_GARANTIA
    , TB_GARANTIA.ID_CONTRATO
    , TB_GARANTIA.ID_TIPO_GARANTIA
    , TB_GARANTIA.ID_ASEGURADORA
    , TB_GARANTIA.TIPO_INGRESO
    , TB_GARANTIA.ID_OBJETO_GARANTIA
    , TB_GARANTIA.ESTADO_GARANTIA
    , TB_GARANTIA.CUSTODIO
    , TB_GARANTIA.FECHA_INGRESO
    , TB_GARANTIA.DESCRIPCION_INGRESO
    , TB_GARANTIA.FECHA_SISTEMA
    , TB_GARANTIA.ID_USUARIO
    , TB_GARANTIA.ID_SESSION
    , TB_GARANTIA.ID_HISTORICO
    , TB_GARANTIA.ID_ESTADO
    , TB_GARANTIA.ID_CONTRATO_MODIFICACION
      FROM TB_GARANTIA
      WHERE TB_GARANTIA.ID_OBJETO_GARANTIA = CAST(O.ID_OBJETO_GARANTIA AS varchar(50))
      ORDER BY FECHA_INGRESO DESC
)  AS RES
```

Aquí ocurre algo similar al caso anterior. Si todos los registros tienen que tener al menos una garantía, entonces, tienes que cambiar el operador outer apply, por el operador cross apply.

La gracia del operador apply, es que la parte interior, se relaciona con la parte exterior.

Ahora bien en este escenario, siempre será mucho mejor, que cambies la definición de la columna id_objeto_Garantia, de varchar(50), por uniqueidentifier, para no tener que hacer ninguna conversión.

Si utilizas el operador apply. Puedes hacer una función.

```
create function fn_ultimaGarantia (@idObjetoGarantia as varchar(50))
returns table
return
(
SELECT TOP(1)
      TB_GARANTIA.ID_GARANTIA
    , TB_GARANTIA.NUMERO_GARANTIA
    , TB_GARANTIA.MONTO_GARANTIA
    , TB_GARANTIA.ID_CONTRATO
    , TB_GARANTIA.ID_TIPO_GARANTIA
    , TB_GARANTIA.ID_ASEGURADORA
    , TB_GARANTIA.TIPO_INGRESO
    , TB_GARANTIA.ID_OBJETO_GARANTIA
    , TB_GARANTIA.ESTADO_GARANTIA
    , TB_GARANTIA.CUSTODIO
    , TB_GARANTIA.FECHA_INGRESO
    , TB_GARANTIA.DESCRIPCION_INGRESO
    , TB_GARANTIA.FECHA_SISTEMA
    , TB_GARANTIA.ID_USUARIO
    , TB_GARANTIA.ID_SESSION
    , TB_GARANTIA.ID_HISTORICO
    , TB_GARANTIA.ID_ESTADO
    , TB_GARANTIA.ID_CONTRATO_MODIFICACION
      FROM TB_GARANTIA
      WHERE TB_GARANTIA.ID_OBJETO_GARANTIA = @idObjetoGarantia
      ORDER BY FECHA_INGRESO DESC
)
```

Y ahora el código, queda mucho más simple.

```
SELECT * FROM TB_OBJETO_GARANTIA O
OUTER APPLY dbo.fn_ultimaGarantia( CAST(O.ID_OBJETO_GARANTIA AS VARCHAR(50))) as fn
```

[image: Resultados]

Si no fuese posible, que un objeto_Garantía no tuviese registros en tb_garantía.

```
SELECT * FROM TB_OBJETO_GARANTIA O
cross APPLY dbo.fn_ultimaGarantia( CAST(O.ID_OBJETO_GARANTIA AS VARCHAR(50)))   as fn
```

Entonces no saldría el tercer objeto.

[image: Solo dos objetos]

Comment: Me falto añadir a la descricion que se tiene que obtener el ultimo registro

Comment: Me falto añadir a la descricion que se tiene que obtener el ultimo registro por ejemplo hay un tipo de objeto_garantia que es "anticipo" y tiene 5 registros ose que tuvo renovacion 4 veces y solo tendria que salir el ultimo de registro

Comment: Modifique la respuesta para que funcione tal cual lo solicitas. Existen varias maneras más de obtener lo que indicas, pero el uso del operador apply te ofrecerá un rendimiento muy bueno, y es muy simple, dejando el código muy limpio.